# Finding the maximum value among the products in two rows

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am an excel beginner and I would like to do the following.

Let `row1= (a_1 a_2 a_3)` and `row2= (b_1 b_2 b_3).`

I want excel to calculate the largest number among the products `(a_1b_1, a_2b_2, a_3b_3).`

It is very difficult to look up these things for I am not sure what kind of calculation I am doing and it is hard to explain.

Comment: Look into the [MAX function](https://support.office.com/en-nz/article/max-function-f7bec1eb-9c66-489a-9166-51d2c9d19333).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a third column, C and enter formula in `C1` as `$A1*$B1`. Pull it down vertically to all other rows so that row number gets incremented for each.

Then in the fourth column, use the formula `MAX(C:C)`

Comment: Hmm, I see so we do it straight forwardly.  I was hoping that there would be a shorter way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

The following formula, array-entered, gives you the *result* of the largest number among the products:

```
{=MATCH(A1:C1*A2:C2)}
```

(provided your data is in A1:C2 in the form you presented it).

For explanations on how to insert array formula in excel see e.g. [this microsoft link](https://support.office.com/en-US/Article/Array-formulas-8ff8257a-b28e-4e81-b4f8-30f793412dfa); in short, you type the formula *without* the curly brackets and confirm with `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER` instead of only `ENTER`.

If you want to find *where* this couple of numbers is (in your case: which column), I would try this:

```
{=MATCH(MAX(A1:C1*A2:C2);A1:C1*A2:C2;0)}
```

(also array-entered).

Answer (score 0):

you can do that, or make a pivot with the raw data and get the MAX/MIN/AVG, based on the pivot options.  I tend to use that instead and then vlookup the ID to the pivot to get whatever aggregate you need.